# Does current get divided into four equal parts for four resistors?

Tags: current, resistors

I have a button that has one pin connected directly to 5v. The other pin has four 4000 ohm resistors connecting to it that then each go into a separate base pin of 4 different transistors. I only want the current to be .001 amps. In theory each base pin should receive .001 amps because 5v going into each resistor of 4000ohms will output .001amps at 1v. I know this because R = voltage drop / current needed. I have 5v I want 1v. 5-1 = 4v. And I need .001amps for my base pin. 4000 = 4/.001  Here is what I want to know. I have 4 base pins. Does my voltage/current from my power source get split into 4 equal parts that go down the 4 resistors or does 5v and the same current go down all resistors. If its the first option, do I just divide my power source current by four?

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words.  I think what you are saying is approximately correct but I may be misinterpreting your circuit.  Add a diagram for clarity.

Comment: " 5v going into each resistor of 4000ohms will output .001amps **at 1v.**" This is only true if the end of the resistor is terminated with something that approximates to a resistance of 1000 ohms. Otherwise it would be 5V **if it is open circuit** or 0V **if it is short circuit**. As you state it is going to the base of a transistor then this would give you about 0.7V and a current of about 1.1mA through the resistor.

Comment: Part tolerances (resistor value, Vbe voltage) will affect the balance of the currents and the current gain of the transistors could amplify (or cancel) this error, but you should be reasonably close unless you have some reason to be exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it splits into four equal (equal only because the resistors are the same value) parts. Each is about 1mA, as you have calculated, so the total current is about 4mA.

Comment: ok. My Arduino 5v pin outputs 450mA. How can I drop that to 1ma for each pin at 1v each. Do I use the formula above. Also does voltage split into 4 parts aswell?

Comment: Your pin can supply 4mA so the voltage **stays** at about 5V and all you need are the 4 resistors.

Comment: @HughKennedy - it doesn't matter how much current a pin can supply (as long as it is enough), what matters is the resistance of the load. From Ohm's law, I=V/R, this calculates the amount of current that is needed. So the fact that the pin can supply more than is needed does not effect the current through the resistor. Think of the "electricity is like water" analogy. The size of a pipe is the resistance, and the voltage the height of water. It doesn't matter how much water (current) is available as long as their is enough to keep the pipe full. More water (current) could keep more pipes full.